# How to get out of the Ice Palace in Zelda A link to the Past?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

I think I'm stuck in the game "Zelda a Link to the Past". I decided to go inside the Ice Palace. To get into the Ice Palace you must use the mirror to go to the Light World. Then, you must move a rock to find a Magical Warp Tile that transfers you to the Dark World. You will be transferred inside the perimeter of the entrance of the Ice Palace.

So I did the beginning of the Ice Palace until I realized I don't have the Hookshot. The Hookshot is located in the Swamp Palace. When I leave the Ice Palace, I have no option but to use the mirror to go to the Light World, because I'm blocked by walls. But now that I've used my mirror to go to the Light World, how can I go back to Dark World?

Comment: The question is not complety clear to me. Let me see if I got it straight. You went to the palace, couldn't complete because of the item, you decided to leave the dungeon, you can't leave because of the walls, you have to use the mirror to back to light world, you used it and now you want to back to dark world outside of the ice palace?

Comment: yes. And now I fill text to reach the 12 minimum characters for new comments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are portals in the light world that will take you directly to the dark world. They are only accessible after first accessing the dark world, and oftentimes are blocked off by  items that you obtain in dark world dungeons.

https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/A_Link_to_the_Past_Warps

The closest one to you is probably also the closest one to the swamp palace. It is located in the screen just north of the swamp palace entrance, behind a row of pegs that can be smashed with the magic hammer.

Comment: I will also add that OP might be confused by how the Mirror works and believe that when you have used the mirror, you can only get back to the Dark World via the sparkly portal you leave behind. However, the portals throughout the Light World (such as the one that took you into the Ice Palace) always work whether or not you have used the mirror.

Comment: @TheHansinator Yeah, I was under that impression as well, that there was a misconception that you had to take the magic mirror's portal to get back. The irony is that to even access the ice palace, the asker would have to take one of these permanent dark world warp portals. That's why I included the link of all those portals, to emphasize that not all of these warps lock you into specific dungeons/regions, as the ice palace's does.

Comment: I have to add that the permanent dark world warps are ALWAYS active, you are technically not required to travel to the dark world first; But, all warp points in the light world are blocked off in such a way that they require an item you can only obtain in the dark world. Also, going through a permanent dark world portal erases any previous mirror portals, allowing you to use the mirror again.

Answer (score 12):

To add to the previous answer, you can get back to the Dark World by walking through the Castle Gate. It will put you at the bottom of the pyramid.

Also, just save outside of Ice Palace in the Dark World. When resuming a Dark World saved game, you appear at the top of the Pyramid.

Comment: Good point, I forgot to mention that saving, quitting, and resuming in the dark world will always start you at the top of the pyramid. Good call. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways you can get into the Dark World and a fourth point in the game where you are transported into the Dark World forcefully:

- Across Hyrule there are eight warp pads that offer you a direct access to the Dark World

  1. On top of Death Mountain south of Hera’s Tower
  2. Between Kakariko and the Lost Woods (needs hammer or Titan’s Mitt)
  3. South of the Eastern Palace (needs hammer)
  4. In the North-West of the Swamp (needs hammer)
  5. The Island in Lake Hylia (needs Titan’s Mitt, the way to access the Ice Palace)
  6. South-Western corner of the desert (needs flute, the only way to get to Misery Mire (called Desert Lake in German, fun fact))
  7. Southern Death Mountain (needs Titan’s Mitt; not one you’ll usually come across)
  8. North-eastern Death Mountain on a little hill that will turn into Turtle Rock (needs hammer and Titan’s Mitt)

  As soon as you are able to reach one, you can access the Dark World whenever you wish; compare the warp pad near Hera’s Tower which you are supposed to use to enter the Tower and recover the Moon Pearl.
- When in the Dark World you can use the mirror to reaccess the Light World; this will leave a teleport location in the Light World at the point where you came back to reaccess the Dark World in the same spot.
- After defeating Agahnim, the castle gate is turned into a warp into the Dark World; it drops you at the foot of the pyramide
- involuntarily, you are warped into the Dark World after defeating Agahnim (upon which the warp at the castle gate is installed).

Each of these methods can be used independently; i.e. even if you used the mirror to leave the Dark World you can still use the warps to enter it at a different spot.

To get to the Swamp Palace, the warp in the North-West of the Swamp is the most convenient but note that you have to go back and forth between the Light World and the Dark World to fully enter the Swamp Palace.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the hookshot to complete the Ice Palace.  You can bomb jump past one of the orange/blue switch rooms and bypass much of the dungeon.

Comment: While true, this does not answer the question, which is how to return to the Dark World after using the mirror. The OP would have run into their stated problem anyway had they managed to beat the dungeon with or without the hookshot.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Arqade.SE! I imagine you may have intended to post this as a comment to the asker's question. Normally, before users can add comments to the comments section of a question or answer, we ask them to build some positive reputation with a good question or answer of their own.